# MediaPlayer, query for all the mp3s in the device and play them

Tags: android, mp3, media-player, android-mediaplayer, audio-player, android-music-player

I am looking for information on the mediaPlayer method

I create a relatively simple java class with only two buttons :play and pause.

I can find instruction on fetching URL or a simple mp3 in the raw file, but what about query for ALL the mp3 files on the device and play them all?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button_stop;
    Button button_play;
    public TextView Textview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        button_play=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);


        mPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

        button_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                try{
                    mPlayer.reset();
                        mPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "");
                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                    mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
                        @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        });



        button_stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                mPlayer.pause();

            }

        });


    }    


}
```

What is the magic formula through which I can fetch ALL the songs on the smartphone and play them all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access External Media Storage.Files in external storage are stored in seperate directories according to their types.For Ex : We have a directory for Pictures,another for ringtones,etc.Music is stored in `DIRECTORY_MUSIC` or if it was downloaded from Internet,also check in `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOAD`

Use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, passing it the type of directory you want, such as DIRECTORY_MUSIC.

For more : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, but yet imagine I had a folder with the songs when I do sports, a folder made by Spotify, a song with the downloads etc. How can I say "look for all the songs in the SD card right away"?

Comment: They would be subfolders in your MUSIC_DIRECTORY,just combine all probable audio directories.Look here for all types in the Field table : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29

I know this is not exactly what you ask for.Maybe someone else would be able to help.